# Ether not programmaticaly sending from one contract to another

Tags: solidity

I have two contracts. My goal is to send ether to contract ContractSendTo with the deposit() method by calling it from ContractSendFrom's depositToSendTo() method. When I execute depositToSendTo(), the Ether remains in ContractSendFrom, and I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract ContractSendTo {

    function deposit() public payable {

    }

    function balance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}

contract ContractSendFrom {
    ContractSendTo contractSendTo;
    constructor(address sendTo) public {
        contractSendTo = ContractSendTo(sendTo);
    }

    function depositToSendTo() public payable {
        contractSendTo.deposit.value(msg.value);   
    }

    function balance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never actually called the `deposit` function in `ContractSendTo`.

The `.value(...)` function returns another function. The value argument is separate from the function arguments. You need another pair of brackets to complete the function call:

```
contractSendTo.deposit.value(msg.value)();
```

If the `deposit` function had any parameters, they would go in the last pair of brackets.